# How to best handle a mother who does not enjoy staying with her kids

Tags: parents, mother

The bonding between mother and child can be compromised early on, for instance by post-partum depression. More rarely, a mother can have difficulty enjoying her time with older kids such as those of age 6, possibly because she sees this maternal role as a duty rather than a fulfillment.

Whenever such bonding is compromised and a mother sees her commitments to her kids mainly as a duty and cannot find inherent gratifications in being a mother, her life can turn badly, with unfavorable consequences for her spouse and the children themselves.

How can this best be handled? Besides individual psychotherapy or family counseling, which practical interventions, in everyday life as well as more in general, can favorably impact on such crisis in motherhood?

Comment: How old are the kids ("older" is a vague range)? Is this being approached from the mother's perspective, or another concerned party (father, mother's friends or family, child)?

Comment: Does the mother say she does not enjoy being with her children, or is this your view of the situation? Is she busy with work, younger children and doing all the childcare and chores to keep the household running? Does she get any time for just herself? Is it possible for you or another adult to mind the children for a little while each day?  We do not yet have enough information to answer you. It could be a very good question.

Answer (score 2):

Well your question is a little bit vague, is it you, who has this problems, your mother, your wife or are you asking for someone else?

Does she have time for herself or is she 24/7 occupied between job and children.

However, generally speaking, she should have from time to time for herself and a little attention from people that are close to her. That helps already a huge amount.

Further, woman have a tendency to keep themselves occupied with appointments when they have problems, to avoid thinking about those problems. But that doesn't necessarily mean that a full calender is caused because of avoiding attempts, it also can be that she is just overthrown with activities, in that case as already said, she needs a little lazy time.

Then there is the question if her work is realized by the ones that she does all the work for, and appreciated. (At work and at home)

Does she get little small gifts from time to time. (That can help much more than someone would think)

These are all things that can help when it is about stress, too much to do and other of these kinds of problems.

However if she is sick, like with post-partum depression, she should see a doctor and that fast, these kind of things can take horrible turns.